# How to override Contact Selector?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, people-picker

I create my custom people editor in SP2010, it replace standart PE in SP and all works fine, but in Infopath 2010 forms it doesn't work.

I read that there is another control, named Contact Selector. Is it possible to replace it on my custom control? Or maybe override standart Selector. Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I create my custom people editor in SP2010... but in Infopath 2010
> forms it doesn't work.
>
> I read that there is another control, named Contact Selector

I am not clear what is your problem and why you have it but I'll try to shoot anyway.
**Contact Selector** is Infopath 2007 control replaced [in Infopath 2010 by Person/Group Picker control](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204000006/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/08/improvements-to-the-person-group-picker-in-infopath-2010.aspx) as well as there are no direct match in controls or formats of Sharepoint and Infopath forms (especially if you are on Sharepoint Foundation, which lacks **IPFS** - Infopath Forms Services permitting to run Infopath forms in browser.

As far as you are lacking in Sharepoint Foundation the ability to run Infopath forms in browser through **IPFS**, the Infopath **People/Grup Picker**  should be configured to query Sharepoint, otherwise they will be picking local computer users and groups which are different from Sharepoint users and groups.
Well, this all depends on you configuration, installation, usage and configuration which you forgot to mention.

So far, from your question, I cannot foresee why there should be problems in using Infopath People/Group Picker in Infopath form.

Comment: Sorry, I should explain why I need to override or replace standart picker. In Sharepoint 2010 there is some problem with People Editor. When it limites by one group you can't find user be query search (it's big problem for large organizations). It's bug or something else. And for solving this problem I create my custom people editor, it work's fine, but later I released that I need the same functionality on Infopath Forms)

Comment: I hope it is clear from both answers that since you are asking about Infopath form, it is a completely different control created, updated, rendered, used differently through different service - IPFS  for browser forms and Infopath Filler if opened on client. There is no sense it its overriding

Answer (score 0):

Thats because, contact selector in Infopath is an ActiveX control, and not the same used in SharePoint. See [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/infopath/using-the-contact-selector-control) for more info

Comment: Your [this-link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/02/28/using-the-contact-selector-control.aspx) is for Infopath 2007. It tells "If you're using InfoPath 2010, then you should check out [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/08/improvements-to-the-person-group-picker-in-infopath-2010.aspx) instead"

Comment: I dont think it would matter, in 2010, they made enhancements to the control, but it is still not the same control as in SharePoint. If you were to write a custom control to override the default behavior in SharePoint, it will not be reflected in Infopath (either you use form services or not).

Comment: The fact that Sharepoint controls and Infopath controls are different  so obvious to me that I am having difficulties to believe that it is the core of the question. Another problem is that if you do not have IPFS and want to access Sharepoint server (which is not obvious from the question) then you need to configure authentication, data source and trust and possibly approve the the published template. Though, again, from the question it is not clear whether it is published to SP server or locally or to a network or to client  computers SP Foundation, etc. or whether it was published at all